# RedirectToAction Throws 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application that uses Integrated Windows Authenticationand calls a Web API hosted on the same IIS server (thus using WindowsIdentity Impersonation for the API calls, which also require the authentication). Most of the routing works, but if an update or create action is executed and I try to redirect the user to the newly created item, I get a 502 Bad Gateway error. The POST/PUT commands go through the Web API and give a response to the MVC application, so I'm thinking this is an IIS configuration issue, or something wrong with the routing.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateIncident(Incident model)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    var identity = User.Identity as WindowsIdentity;

    async Task Action()
    {
        response = await _service.CreateIncident(model);
    }
    async Task GetId()
    {
        model.IncidentTrackingRefId = await _service.GetNewIncidentId(model.IncidentCategoryLookupTableId,
            model.IncidentTypeLookupTableId);
    }

    await WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(identity.AccessToken, GetId);
    await WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(identity.AccessToken, Action);

    if (response == null) return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("View", "Incidents", new { id = model.IncidentId });
    }
}
```

View action:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> View(int id)
{
    var identity = User.Identity as WindowsIdentity;

    async Task Action()
    {
        ViewBag.BusTypes = await _service.GenerateDropDown("/GetIncidentBusTypes");
    }

    Incident incident = null;

    async Task GetIncident()
    {
        incident = await _service.GetIncidentById(id);
    }

    await WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(identity.AccessToken, GetIncident);
    await WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(identity.AccessToken, Action);

    if (ViewBag.BusTypes == null || incident == null) return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
    return View(incident);
}
```

Comment: `RedirectToAction` causes a 302 response to be sent to the client with the URL route to the action set as the `Location` header. This is standard HTTP stuff. At that point, the request-response cycle is complete. However, usually, the client will then issue a new *GET* request for the URL in the `Location` header. It looks like you're trying to redirect to an action that only responds to POST with a payload. Both of which are not possible.

Comment: I added in the View() action to my OP. I have it specified as an HttpGet with the attribute tag in my code, so I don't think your point about redirect is correct in this instance.

Comment: @RobertMcCoy the MVC application and WebAPI application you've mentioned are two separate IIS Web applications?

Comment: @laika Yes, both using Integrated Windows Authentication and verifying against AD groups for authorization. The WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated() sends the authentication to the Web API.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `model` in RedirectToAction. Redirect to action has these overloads:

```
RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(string actionName);
RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(string actionName, object routeValues);
RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(string actionName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues);
RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(string actionName, string controllerName);
RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues);
RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues);
```

Meaning, you can't pass the whole object to this method.

Comment: The error lies in this line 

`return RedirectToAction("View", "Incidents", new { id = model.IncidentId });`

And I'm not quite sure why, but it's like it's not forwarding the request properly to the action, thus the 502. That overload follows the actionName, controllerName, routeValues specifics.

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot redirect to another application** using `RedirectToAction`.

Suppose you have configured MVC routes in this manner

```
routes.MapRoute(
     "Default",
     "Support/{controller}/action-{action}/{id}",
     new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

Then if you use `RedirectToAction` in your controller

```
return RedirectToAction("View", "Incidents", new { id = model.IncidentId })
```

the browser receives this response

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://example.com/Support/Incidents/action-View/123
```

However if you are redirecting to another target application, then the current application, which is handling the request, have no knowledge what is the route table configuration in target application - it does not even know whether it's using MVC at all.

**Long story short**, if you want to redirect to another application use [`Redirect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirect(v=vs.118).aspx).

Example:

```
return Redirect("~/../Application2/Incidents/View");
```

Comment: But the redirects are all happening in the MVC application. The Web API is just following the REST API Standards and returning the normal response codes of OK, Created, No Content, Not Found, Bad Request, etc., and based upon these responses in the `HttpResponseMessage` redirects are thrown (if needed).

Comment: @RobertMcCoy The `Incidents` controller and `View` action are in the MVC or Web API?

Comment: The Incidents controller is in the MVC application, and calls the Web API (through `_services` which is just a class called `IncidentRESTService` to handle all API interactions). Then the response should be parsed/handled based upon status code or content. Like I said, the POST/PUT requests go through, and the correct URL is put in the address bar of the browser, for example after creating a new Incident I get `https://application/Incidents/View/55` in the URL bar, but it throws a 502 Bad Gateway error. I'm thinking this might just be an IIS error at this point?

Comment: I did a little bit more digging and went through the logs and event viewer on the remote server. Logs are all fine, and the application viewer doesn't have any errors directly related to the 502 bad gateway...but it does have an error that appears to be happening randomly that is associated with ASP.NET Core: `Faulting application name: dotnet.exe, Faulting module name: System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll`